# SQL Server - Sakila DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm currently using MS's Sakila DB which consists of data on movies/actors/rentals/customers etc.

Map:

[image: Sakila Map]

I've been asked to formulate a query to find customers who have not rented a particular film.

I've been able to work out my code for finding the customers who **have** rented the film, but I can't get my head around getting the list who haven't.

My code below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.customer_id, C.first_name, C.last_name
FROM customer AS C
JOIN RENTAL AS R ON C.customer_id = R.customer_id
JOIN inventory AS I ON R.inventory_id = I.inventory_id
JOIN film AS F ON I.film_id = F.film_id
WHERE F.title = 'ANGELS LIFE'
```

I can use `!= 'ANGELS LIFE'`  however that will return me a list of everyone who has rented any other film (including the ones who have rented ANGELS LIFE from their other purchases).

I cannot work out the next step. I've considered using `Union` and then removing the duplicates (where count(*) >1) perhaps?

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use do aggregation :

```
SELECT C.customer_id, C.first_name, C.last_name
FROM customer AS C JOIN 
     RENTAL AS R 
     ON C.customer_id = R.customer_id JOIN 
     inventory AS I 
     ON R.inventory_id = I.inventory_id JOIN 
     film AS F 
     ON I.film_id = F.film_id
GROUP BY C.customer_id, C.first_name, C.last_name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN F.title = 'ANGELS LIFE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you! Had considered HAVING but figured i had the same issue as WHERE. Great solution to re-define the result and then filter it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `not exists` with a correlated subquery. This looks to me like a simple and straight-forward phrasing of what you asked for:

```
select c.*
from customer c
where not exists (
    select 1
    from rental r
    inner join inventory i on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
    inner join film f on f.film_id = i.film_id
    where f.title = 'ANGELS LIFE' and r.customer_id = c.customer_id
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Have tried both methods and learnt something new.
Would you mind briefly explaining what the **select 1** is doing here as opposed to select * ?

Comment: @HarryH247: `exists` just checks if the subquery returns *something*, regardless of how many rows or their content. So we just use `select 1` - that's a convention, it could very well be `select 0`, `select *` or `select null`, it does not really matter.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Have just had a play around with exists and definitely something i'll read up on. Thanks for taking the time to reply!